# Output page from Page ID in query_string

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string

An example of the query_string would be: **testdev.com/test-results/?Title=166**

I have the following code below. What I can't figure out is how to set up the last array to get the ID and then produce the correct post accordingly. (the relation can be ignored, the other arrays I have are working and weren't needed for the example)

Any tips/help would be appreciated

```
<?php


      **THIS IS WHERE I TRIED TO GET THE ID**
      $queryTitle = $_GET['Title'];
      $pageTitle = the_title();

      $args = array(
          // all your args here
          'post_type'    => 'resorts',
          'meta_query' => array(
              'relation' => 'OR',
               array( **THIS IS WHERE I TRIED TO GET THE TITLE FROM THE URL**
                  'key' => $pageTitle,
                  'value' => $queryTitle,
                  'compare' => '=',
               ),   
          )
      );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

      if($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>

content etc goes here

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p>No results found, modify your search criteria and try again!</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_page()` could be used:

```
$queryTitle = $_GET['Title'];
$your_page = get_page($queryTitle);
echo $your_page->post_title;
```

Comment: I updated my post to be more generic, I got caught up in the title concept.  Its How can I get the post to output from the id.  So that could be titles,content,etc.  And how that fits into the array

Comment: how would I go about adding that do the array so I can get the post content?
`array(
                  'key' => $queryTitle,
                  'value' => $your_page,
                  'compare' => '=',
              )`